# Jquery modify select (multiple) value

Tags: jquery

I am aware that you can use `.val()` to change which options are selected in a select `multiple=multiple` but,

How can you simply select/deselect one option, without changing the state of the other options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case it's easiest to de-select the particular option:

```
$("#select option[value='"+val+"']").removeAttr("selected");
```

Comment: thankyou `option[value='"+val+"']` is what i was looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to use jquery for everything.

```
var el = $(..)[0];
el.options[i].selected = false;
```

Comment: This doesn't use the *value* to select by, it's an index, and also you used jQuery :)